# Get n characters every n characters from a string efficiently

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working with a string containing an image in rgba (8bit per channel), so every four characters of the string is one pixel and each character is one channel of that pixel, e.g.:

```
#4x4 pixel image
img_str = 'rgbargbargbargba'
```

Now imagine a much bigger image, extracting the alpha channel is really fast using:

```
img_str_a = img_str[3::4]
# result applying this to the 4x4 image would be 'aaaa'
```

This executes in around 2ms for a 1350x765 image. But now I need to extract the RGB channels, ending with a string like 'rgbrgbrgbrgb' with the 4x4 image. I tried with this:

```
img_str_rgb = ''.join('' if i%4 == 0 else char for i, char in enumerate(img_str, 1))
```

Which works, but it takes around 700ms for the same 1350x765 image. That's a lot, as I'm processing video, so I need much much lower times.

Comment: why not use `numpy`?

Comment: A couple more inputs and expected outputs would be useful in understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I didn't try with numpy, will do some tests. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of joining single characters, join substrings:

```
img_str_rbg = ''.join(img_str[j:j+3] for j in xrange(0, len(img_str), 4))
```

Even faster, you can use `zip`, or for python2 `izip`:

```
from itertools import izip, imap
img_str_rgb = ''.join(imap(''.join, izip(img_str[0::4], img_str[1::4], img_str[2::4])))
```

For your scenario, `numpy` is better:

```
import numpy as np
img = np.fromstring(img_str,dtype=np.byte).reshape(765,1350,4)
img_alpha = img[:, :, 3]
img_rgb = img[:, :, :3]
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, but that still takes too much time (around 220ms for the 1350x765 image) I would need it to be around 5ms, don't know if that's even possible.

Comment: then use `numpy`.

Comment: Thanks! Numpy is much faster.